# Building Setting only showing Export option/button for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk, game-engine

[image]

**Build and run not showing up**

Im using the Unity version 2017.3.1f1

Need  a solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in Export mode. Notice how left button also changes from *Build* to *Export* when in export mode too. That is used to export your Unity project to Android project which can be opened with IDE's like Eclipse and Android Studio then built with them.

If you want to build and run the project from Unity, uncheck the *Export Project* checkbox and the *Build And Run* button should be enabled again.

[image]